# Error "error: ‘Matrix3x3’ is not a member of ‘tf’" while building bosch-ros-pkg

Tags: ros, bullet, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got errors while building some packages separately in [`bosch_shared_autonomy`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bosch_shared_autonomy#) (pkgs are: safe_teleop_{ base, pr2, stage }). All errors look similar as the one below.

```
  :
  /home/user/link/bosch-ros-pkg-sourceforge/stacks/bosch_shared_autonomy/safe_teleop_base/src/safe_trajectory_planner.cpp:402: error: ‘Matrix3x3’ is not a member of ‘tf’
  /home/user/link/bosch-ros-pkg-sourceforge/stacks/bosch_shared_autonomy/safe_teleop_base/src/safe_trajectory_planner.cpp:402: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘matrix’
  /home/user/link/bosch-ros-pkg-sourceforge/stacks/bosch_shared_autonomy/safe_teleop_base/src/safe_trajectory_planner.cpp:403: error: ‘matrix’ was not declared in this scope
  :
```

I've seen a few questions that ask about similar/the same error message (e.g. [this](http://questions.ros.org/question/12983/compiling-error-on-microstrain_3dmgx2_imu-package/?answer=19162)), but the solutions to those questions haven't been informative for my case since they seem to be case-dependent.

My machine has `diamondback`, `electric` and `fuerte` installed. `$ROS_ROOT` points to `electric`. Full error message is here http://pastebin.com/hv455D5Z

Any idea would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35759/error-%22error:-%E2%80%98matrix3x3%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of-%E2%80%98tf%E2%80%99%22-while-building-bosch-ros-pkg/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this announcement](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=77347&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=20) for details, but for Electric you have to use the Bullet library, and for Fuerte you have to use the tf library. You can either change the code to continue using Electric, or you can set your ROS installation to Fuerte. To do that, in your `~/.bashrc` file use

```
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
```

So it appears that the Bosch package has been built for Fuerte and is no longer backwards compatible with Electric. To get it working with Electric you would have to install and change their source code.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0